# Calculate Heading with two GPS Devices

Tags: c, gps, robotics

Hi I am planing to use two RTK-GPS devices to get the position and heading of a outdoor robot. The two devices are placed on the left and the right side of the robot with a distance of 2m. The heading should be a value between 0 and 2*PI. 0 if the robot is facing north.

I am trying the following:

```
double x1 = gps_left->latitude;
double y1 = gps_left->longitude;
double x2 = gps_right->latitude;
double y2 = gps_right->longitude;

double dx = x2-x1;
double dy = y2-y1;

// get the normal of the line
double nx = dy*-1;
double ny = dx;

double angle = atan2(ny ,nx);
```

somehow the angle always stays the same even if i rotate the robot

Comment: It might be useful to add some examples of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` values that your robot has captured. My suspicion is that both GPS units may be returning the same values, given their likely resolution and the separation of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
double x1 = gps_left->latitude;
double y1 = gps_left->longitude;
double x2 = gps_right->latitude;
double y2 = gps_right->longitude;

double dy = y2-y1;

double nx = cos(x2)*sin(dy);
double ny = cos(x1)*sin(dy) - sin(x1)*cos(x2)*cos(dy);

double angle = atan2(nx,ny);
```

Can you try this?

0 - heading north,
90 - heading east,
180 - heading south,
270 - heading west.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mark Booth the resolution might not be enough. We had a similar issue, so we used a magnetometer to fix this. Using this heading information from a magnetometer and GPS we were able to navigate successfully.